# How to determine the index size with pymongo?

Tags: mongodb, pymongo

With monogdb, I can run `db.collection.stats()` to find the size, in bytes, for each index.

PyMongo seems to be missing this operation.

Is there a way to find this information with PyMongo?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

```
import pymongo
connect = pymongo.Connection('mongodb://localhost', safe=True)
db = connect.test
db.command('collStats', 'collection')
```

Result:

```
{
  u'count': 2,
  u'ns': u'test.test2',
  u'ok': 1.0,
  u'lastExtentSize': 8192,
  u'avgObjSize': 94.0,
  u'totalIndexSize': 8176,
  u'systemFlags': 1,
  u'userFlags': 0,
  u'numExtents': 1,
  u'nindexes': 1,
  u'storageSize': 8192,
  u'indexSizes': {u'_id_': 8176},
  u'paddingFactor': 1.0,
  u'size': 188
}
```

P.S. `test2` in the result is my collection name

- http://api.mongodb.org/python/current/api/pymongo/database.html
- http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/collection-statistics/